# Finite Direct product of solvable groups is solvable

Tags: group-theory, direct-product, solvable-groups

[image]

I found this proof. But among my colleagues it is rumored that there is a mistake. Could you tell me if I did, what would the mistake be? I really don't have much idea how this proof works.

Comment: It looks correct, but also way more complicated that necessary.

Comment: Alternatively, show that $[G\times H,G\times H]=[G,G]\times[H,H]$ and use induction on the number of factors.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text

Answer (score 3):

> where $H_{11}$ is the smallest nontrivial subgroup of $G_1$ in a composition series...

That makes sense only when each $G_i$ is finite. Infinite solvable groups don't even have composition series: [A solvable group with composition series is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737274/a-solvable-group-with-composition-series-is-finite) and don't have to have minimal subgroups.

The general solution would be due to:

> **Lemma.** Let $G$ be a group and $H\subseteq G$ a normal subgroup. Then $G$ is solvable if and only if both $H$ and $G/H$ are.

For a proof see this: [For $G$ a group and $H\unlhd G$, then $G$ is solvable iff $H$ and $G/H$ are solvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39814/for-g-a-group-and-h-unlhd-g-then-g-is-solvable-iff-h-and-g-h-are-solv)

With that we automatically obtain that $G\times H$ is solvable if and only if both $G$ and $H$ are. And then we apply a simple induction to conclude that $G_1\times\cdots\times G_n$ is solvable if and only if each $G_i$ is.